# VBA getdate function (?)

Tags: vba, function, excel, date

I wonder if there's any function in VBA which convert strings into a date?
I mean I work with dates with different formats e.g. 20150723, 07023015, 23-07-15 etc. -it's the same date for me, but VBA editor does not know it:)

What's the best way to get "real" date 2015/07/23 from string 20150723 ?

Comment: Look at using CDate(strDate)

Comment: For that specific format: `cdate(format("20150723", "0000-00-00"))`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for,
thanks for help!

Comment: @Rory  Consider posting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your specific example, you can use:

```
cdate(format("20150723", "0000-00-00"))
```

which converts "20150723" into "2015-07-23" which should be recognisable to CDate as a date string.